# A conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to diverge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, conditional-convergence

I'm thinking about the following problem:

"Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ be a conditionally convergent series;
show that there exists a bijection $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_{f(m)}$ diverges to $+\infty$, or more precisely that $\liminf_{N\to\infty} \sum_{m=N}^{\infty} a_{f(m)}=\limsup_{N\to\infty}\sum_{m=N}^{\infty} a_{f(m)}$".

Intuitively, I think I could make such a rearrangement by choosing an arbitrary $M\in\mathbb{R}^+$, then add positive terms $a_n \geq 0$ (of which there is an infinite number,  as I've previously shown) until the sum exceeds $M$, then add one negative term $a_n <0$ then add positive terms until the sum exceeds $2\cdot M$, then add one negative term, and so on.

However, I'm not sure about whether this works and, if it does, how to make it rigorous so I would appreciate any hint/comment/help about how to make this argument correct.

Best regards,

lorenzo.

Comment: By the way, you could have a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: @Watson it seems to me that the Wikipedia article only looks at the case of rearranging a conditionally convergent series to make it converge to a real number, and only briefly mentions the case of rearranging such a series to make it diverge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the situation is not the same. When you want a finite limit, you alternative overshoot (using the $A_+=\{n:a_n>0\}$ elements) and undershoot (using the $A_-=\{n:a_n\leq 0\}$ elements). In the infinite case you never finish the first overshoot so you will not exhaust the set $A_-$.

Your suggestion, however, is fine. Here is a way to write it out:

Enumerate $A_+$ and $A_-$, calling the sequences $a^+_j$ and $a^-_j$ ($j\geq 1$). Then define inductively: $T_0=0$ and 
  $$ T_M=  \inf \left\{ p> T_{M-1} : \sum_{1\leq j\leq p} a^+_j + \sum_{1\leq i<M} a^-_i > M \right\} $$
You first use $T_1$ elements from $A_+$ (to exceed 1), then one element from $A_-$ then $T_2-T_1$ elements from $A_+$ (to exceed 2), next element from $A_-$ etc..  To write down a bijection explicitly, denote:

$$ \phi_+: {\Bbb N} \rightarrow A_+ \ \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \
 \phi_-:  {\Bbb N} \rightarrow A_- $$
the monotone bijections with the sets of positive/negative elements.
We then define a bijection $ \phi:  {\Bbb N} \rightarrow  {\Bbb N} $
as follows:  For $k\in {\Bbb N}$ of the form $k=T_j+j$ for some $j\geq 1$ we set:
$$\phi(k)=\phi_-(j)$$ and for $T_j+j+1\leq k \leq T_{j+1}+j$ for some  $j\geq 0$ we set:
$$ \phi(k) = \phi_+(k-j)$$
As $T_j$ is monotone in $j$ one verifies that $\phi$ is indeed a bijection and that
$$\sum_{k=1}^N a_{\phi(k)} \rightarrow +\infty$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I think another possible rearrangement would be the following: we define the sequence of natural numbers $n_j$ by setting $n_j:=\min\{n\in A_+ :n\neq n_i \forall i<j\}$ if $\sum_{0\leq i<j} a_{n_i}\leq i$ and $n_j:=\min\{n\in A_−:n\neq n_i \forall i<j\}$ if $\sum_{0\leq i<j} a_{n_i} > i$. I think this should work but I haven't been able to prove that $\liminf_N\to\infty\sum_{m=N}^\infty a_{f(m)}=\limsup_{N\to\infty}\sum_{m=N}^\infty a_{f(m)}=+\infty$ (where we set $f(i):=n_i \forall i$). What do you think about this?

Comment: @lorenzo  The condition $\sum_{0\leq i<j} a_{n_i}\leq i$ doesn't make sense (with i on the RHS). You could try to replace it by $j$ but then you may never finish exhausting $A_+$ (and thus never use all of $A_-$).

Comment: @ H.H.Rugh : Ok; in your post you say that "Writing down the precise bijection with the original sequence can be done but is lengthy": since the bijection is exactly what I'm looking for, could you give me an hint about how to write it down in full detail? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your proof and I've a question: what if the $T_M$ exhaust all the natural numbers, i.e. $\sum_{1\leq j\leq p} a_j ^+ +\sum_{1\leq i <M} a_i ^- >M\  \forall p\in\mathbb{N}$? Then no element from $A^-$ will be used. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: The $T_M$ for a fixed $M$ would exhaust the elements fro $A_+$ if there was no finite $p$ for which the condition was satisfied. But this corresponds to $\sum_j a_j^+ <+\infty$ so the sequence from the start was not conditionally convergent.